Removing attribute values from Dynamodb getItem response
I have create an direct connection from API gateway to DynamoDB using the AwsIntegration.
It works but the problem is that I get all the attribute values
{
  "Item": {
    "properties": {
      "M": {
        "requireLogin": {
          "BOOL": false
        },

like M and BOOL. I want to have the direct values such as {"properties": {"requireLogin": false}} returned.
The payload is pretty long and have different different types like S, L, etc. so the solution needs to be generic
I have tried an bunch of thing using VTL in the responseTemplates, different flags but nothing seems to work.
My CDK code looks like this:
    const dynamoIntegration = new AwsIntegration({
      service: 'dynamodb',
      action: 'GetItem',
      options: {
        credentialsRole: apiGatewayRole,
        integrationResponses: [
          {
            statusCode: '200',
          },
          ...errorResponses,
        ],
        requestTemplates: {
          'application/json': JSON.stringify({
            TableName: DELIVERY_TABLE,
            Key: {
              [partitionKey]: {
                S: "$input.params('pagePath')",
              },
            },
          }),
        },
      },
    });
    
    deliveryApi.root.addMethod('GET', dynamoIntegration, {
      apiKeyRequired: !isLocalStack,
      requestParameters: {
        'method.request.querystring.pagePath': true,
      },
      methodResponses: [
        {
          statusCode: '200',
          responseModels: {
            'application/json': deliveryApi.addModel('ResponseModel', {
              contentType: 'application/json',
              modelName: 'ResponseModel',
              schema: {},
            }),
          },
        },
      ],
    });

I have a solution where it goes through a lambda and does unmarshall but I would like to avoid this overhead :)
I'm expecting a response without any of the attribute values like this:
{"properties": {"requireLogin": false}}


You have to use the integration response mapping and unmarshall manually. For example:
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
    "comments": [
        #foreach($elem in $inputRoot.Items) {
            "commentId": "$elem.commentId.S",
            "userName": "$elem.userName.S",
            "message": "$elem.message.S"
        }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
    ]
}

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-integration-settings-integration-response.html
Alternatively, unmarshall using the DynamoDB client on your client side.

Thank you for answering! :)
I have seen documentation, but the problem is that I have too many fields to map manually and that the field changes. I hoped to find a VTL script or something that could help solving it to avoid the manual process or a util method like: $util.dynamodb.toMapValues.
It seems like a common problem, but maybe it is just me?

Most people don't use VTL for mapping specifically because of this type of problem.

Okay, so there is no other solution than to manual map the fields or do an unmarshal client-side? :)

Or proxy to Lambda
